# How to get data from Firestore in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a Welcome Message where the user's name is placed in the top left corner when logged in. I succeeded in getting `user.email` and `user.uid` using `final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;` and `User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;`, but I don't know how to get user's other data(especially name).

My code is:

```
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  ...

    Widget loginMessage() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(
            // I want to username at here.
              '${user.email}님, \n환영합니다 :)',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: titleLarge,
                fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _signOut().then(
                  (value) => Get.to(
                    () => HomeScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Text('로그아웃'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        marginHeight22,
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // 로그인버튼
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Get.to(() => LoginScreen());
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: primaryColor20,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: primaryColor20,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(12.0),
                  ),
                ),
                height: 48,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    '내 정보 수정',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: primaryColor50,
                      fontFamily: 'semi-bold',
                      fontSize: titleSmall,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

[image: Firebase Database Image]
[image: Simulator Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey for storing other user details you have to create a collection in the firebase database just sharing how I do

so I have a collection called users where the document ID is the user uid generated by firebase and it has various fields like name, avatar, username etc.

So for the above scenario, the query is like

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userUid).snapshots();
```

To display the data from the snapshot

```
DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data!.docs.map().data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
return ListTile(title: Text(data['username']));
```